# Heroku fork not working. Says app already exists no matter what name I give

Tags: heroku, heroku-toolbelt

I am giving this command to fork app a***e-a*****e-94769 to another called rd-test

`heroku fork --from a***e-a*****e-94769 --to rd-test`

It says `Forking a***e-a*****e-94769... app rd-test already exists.`

But I don't see any such app.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

App names are global in scope as they all become https://appname.herokuapp.com. So that message is telling you that someone else has already used `rd-test`. Try something more unique.

Comment: I had tried changing the name also, but probably it was not "more unique" as you say. It worked today. Thanks.